# UIView's bounds size vs frame size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

Can a frame's size be different from the bound's size of a UIView.

Whenever I set either of them, I notice that both change and they are always in sync. Is there an edge case where this is not true?

Answer (score 5):

Yes; for example, a transformed (e.g. rotated) view has a different (and useless) frame size.

The frame is purely a convenience, and you could live entirely without it if you had to; the bounds size and center, together, accurately and always describe the view's position and size.

Comment: You might want to read my book on this topic, starting here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_frame

Comment: I wouldn't say a transformed frame is **useless**. If you wanted to know the area occupied by a rotated view so the superview could lay out something based on that, the frame is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Please refer the below simple difference between frame and bound:-

> The frame of a view is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y)
>   and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained
>   within.

> The bounds of a view is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y)
>   and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system.

Comment: Bounds does not always have an origin of (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

`bounds` "describes the view’s location and size in its own coordinate system".

`frame` "defines the origin and dimensions of the view in the coordinate system of its superview".

So the two should differ for any view that uses a different coordinate system than its parent. The key giveaway is:

> However, if the transform property contains a non-identity transform,
>   the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be
>   modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center
>   property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.

So that's an example Apple gives you of when `frame` is defined not to have a predictable relationship to `bounds`: whenever you've set a non-identity transform.

(source for all quotes was [the UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView))

Answer (score 0):

They are different.

Assume I have a label:

`label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20)`

Its current frame & bounds (`print(label.frame, label2.bounds)`) are as follows:
`(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 20.0) (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 20.0)`

Note they are currently the same. It is shown in x-position, y-position, width, height (in that order).

Now I will apply a scale Y of 2 to the label like so:

`label.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 2)`

Its new frame & bounds are as follows:

`(0.0, -10.0, 200.0, 40.0) (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 20.0)`

Notice how its own bounds are still the same, while the frame has changed (height went from 20 to 40, and the y-position has shifted by 10 upwards to compensate for the 20 increase so it will remain centred).

This corresponds to what other answers/documentation are saying. Neither are useless, use it accordingly to your needs.

7 years late to the party but hope this still helps others.